# Azure. Owin OpenId authentication. Added custom claims. AuthorizationCodeReceived is not called

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, owin, openid, katana

I've almost configured my `OpenId` `owin` `authentication`/`authorization` in `Azure Active Directory`. My configuration is the following:

```
 app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
 {
     CookieName = "AppServiceAuthSession"
 });

 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
 {

     ClientId = ClientId,
     Authority = _authority,
     PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
     RedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
     Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
     {
           AuthenticationFailed = context =>
           {
                 context.HandleResponse();
                 context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                 return Task.FromResult(0);
           },                   
           AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
           {
                 var id = new ClaimsIdentity(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                 id.AddClaims(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims);
                 var appToken = "MyToken";
                 id.AddClaim(new Claim("MyTokenKey", appToken));

                 context.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket
                 (
                      new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType),
                        context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                 );
           }
            },
        });
```

But I want to add one more application *token* (not user token) to claims list to be able to have ability to use this token in any place on my site. Also it's good point for me that I don't need to get this token from my external token provider more then one time per an authentication session.

But place, where I'm going to add my logic (`AuthorizationCodeReceived` as well as other methods from `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications`) is called only when I use my local IIS(run locally), when I try to use azure IIS, this method has not been called at all. In this case my User is authenticated anyway, but this method and the similar methods from `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications`(except `RedirectToIdentityProvider`) are not fired.

I've downloaded the git source code of `Katana` project and referenced this project to my instead of the official nuget packages to debug its and as I think currently, I've found the reason why it happens. The `AuthorizationCodeReceived` "event" method is called from `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler` class in `AuthenticateCoreAsync` method. But also, the calling of this method is required that the below checking must give the *true* result:

```
 if (string.Equals(Request.Method, "POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.ContentType) // May have media/type; charset=utf-8, allow partial match.
 && Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
 && Request.Body.CanRead)
 {
 //some necessary preparation to call `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event method
 }
```

As we can see, this checking allows only `POST` requests and I see these `POST` requests when I run app in *local IIS*, but I cannot see these `POST` requests when I deploy my application in *azure portal* (I've debugged both of options : on *local IIS* and in *azure portal*). 
As summary  from the above, this is the only one difference between these runnings. (Azure IIS doesn't send `POST` request at all by some reason).Any other methods in `Katana` project (which I checked) are called in the same way.

Could anybody help with it?

PS Note, I check any changes only after clearing of browser data (cache/history and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the following:

[image: Auth configuration]

The authorization in azure portal should be configured as shown above. In case if you chose `LogIn with Azure Active Directory`, then app services auth takes place outside of your app, and the custom authorization is not triggered.